# How to overlap two circles?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Can someone help me get this layout with the first circle over the second?
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X31pD.png)

I have this function:

```
Widget overlapped() {
  final overlap = 25;
  final items = [
    Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 2),
      decoration: new BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.blue,
        shape: BoxShape.circle,
      ),
      child: CircleAvatar(
        radius: 22,
        backgroundImage: AssetImage('assets/example_logo.png'),
        backgroundColor: Colors.black,
      ),
    ),
    CircleAvatar(
        radius: 22,
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        child: ClipOval(
            child: Image.network(
          "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/53/Google_%22G%22_Logo.svg/1200px-Google_%22G%22_Logo.svg.png",
          errorBuilder: (context, exception, stackTrace) {
            return Container(color: Colors.white);
          },
          height: 35,
        ))),
    CircleAvatar(
        child: Text('+2', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).canvasColor),
  ];

  List<Widget> stackLayers = List<Widget>.generate(items.length, (index) {
    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(index.toDouble() * overlap, 0, 0, 0),
      child: items[index],
    );
  });

  return Stack(children: stackLayers);
}
```

This function whenever I add an item to the array, it adds a widget on the right. But I want the first to be above the second, the second of the third, etc ...

Answer (score 2):

you could use the Stack widget :

```
        Stack(
         children:<Widget>:[
Positioned(
           right: 130.0, 
          child:Container(
        shape: BoxShape.circle,
          
     )
    ),
          Positioned(
           left: 130.0, 
          child:Container(
        shape: BoxShape.circle,
          
     )
    ),
    
        ]
        )
```

Comment: The answer is more or less correct, but the left widget should come after the right one in the `children` array so it would be drawn "on top of" the right widget. Stack draws its first child then second on top of that then third one on top of that etc.

Comment: @nstosic, You're right, I missed it, I'll edit the answer.

Comment: @nstosic Is there no way to change the order in the Stack? I want the first widget in the array to be on top of the second, and the second on top of the third.

Comment: The easiest way would be to change the order in the array. The `Stack` always draws the latter child on top of the former. You'd need to extend `RenderStack` and override `void paint(PaintingContext context, Offset offset)` which is rather difficult to do without side effects

Answer (score 1):

Use `Stack` and `Positioned` together.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class OverLap extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Overlap'),
      ),
      body: Container(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        width: 500.0,
        child: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            //Change according to your icon
            Icon(
              Icons.flaky,
              size: 50.0,
              color: Colors.red,
            ),
            Positioned(
              left: 20.0,
              //Change according to your icon
              child: Icon(
                Icons.flaky,
                size: 50.0,
                color: Colors.blue,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```